# Could not load facebook avatar image

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook avatar url from requesting graph:

https://graph.facebook.com/1382937585156604/picture?type=large

But I can not download this both in browser and app, before it did work using `imageView.kf.setImage(with: url)` from `Kingfisher`. But now I don't know why it could not be downloaded.

The error says:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified
>   hostname could not be found."
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x60000064fb40 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1003 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12}},
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://scontent.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/13934572_1021586177958415_8257832708833676680_n.jpg?oh=70f8a5971ca2214bf1167879074ce0ca&oe=5A415F24,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://scontent.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/13934572_1021586177958415_8257832708833676680_n.jpg?oh=70f8a5971ca2214bf1167879074ce0ca&oe=5A415F24,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not
>   be found.}

with errorCode: 1003

My ReadPermission is: ["email", "public_profile"].

Comment: Have you tried the completion handler to see if you're getting an error?

Comment: Also check if you have permission to access image, if not first take the permission for profile image access.

Comment: @Callam it says Error Domain.

Comment: "worked before and does not work anymore" is usually an indication of a bug. there is one open for the avatar image right now, sorry if it is not related but i am pretty sure it is the same issue. there is a bug link in that other thread.

Comment: Is there a more specific error message, perhaps an error code?

Comment: Hi @Callam, I've updated the specific error message and error code.

Comment: Facebook developers have just fixed this.